# how do i send cloud message in flutter application using cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have a firestore database [firestore database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qACUv.png)

How do I write a cloud function to send a cloud message to all the app users when one of the fields in the firestore database is updated? in my case when the price of the price_change_pct field goes below the value -1 ?

Comment: all the fields in the database are stored as a string

Comment: Do you look for realtime database feature?

Comment: yes, the database updates every 10 min

Comment: Does the update have a static frequency? If so, why don't you perform a request from the client to update the data on this frequency?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [link](https://jude-m.medium.com/send-push-notifications-with-flutter-firebase-cloud-messaging-and-functions-5e9942a7f23c), where as stated:

> You can invoke a Cloud Function from the Flutter app either through HTTP or a database trigger and let the Cloud Function do the work for
> you. Inside the function use the Firebase Admin SDK and send messages as you wish.

In the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple), the whole description related to Firebase messaging for the  multiple devices has been explained briefly.
You can also refer to the [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68734993/15774176) and [case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67114386/15774176) where the community resolved a similar issue.

Comment: @srikanth Posted an answer, Is it helpful?